# Why did virtual user "community" reject a tag edit?

Tags: discussion, support

I just tried to add tag "india" to this [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32738/officially-5-days-working-but-we-work-on-many-alternate-saturdays-to-get-things), but the "virtual user" "community" instantly rejected this edit.

Why did this happen? Should that happen at all?

Comment: it's likely your edit was auto-rejected by grace period editing made by someone else: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153403/add-a-reject-reason-when-the-community-user-rejects-an-edit

Comment: @gnat Thanks! I tried again, and now it is "pending review".

Comment: for the reference, link to the rejected edit is: **[http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20238](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20238)**

Comment: Shog said [issue is fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153403/add-a-reject-reason-when-the-community-user-rejects-an-edit/238413?noredirect=1#comment781529_238413). I tested - this is indeed so, [more recent rejected edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20277) now shows "Conflicted with a subsequent edit"

Comment: Community is a cold, heartless monster that flags and tags and all kinds of other -ags inappropriately. But we love it anyway. But seriously, if I had a dollar for every time I cleaned up a flag Community issued when it didn't need to, I could ... well I couldn't retire, but I could take my wife out to a nice dinner and maybe a movie too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the fancy mod timeline view, and [gnat's right](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2879/why-did-virtual-user-community-reject-a-tag-edit#comment6384_2879), someone else made an edit that overrode yours. It was just bad timing.